# Write a Doctrine2 query to join two spatial tables

Tags: symfony, join, doctrine-orm, postgis, spatial

I am using Symfony with Doctrine2 on a Postgre database with PostGIS enabled.  I have two tables - property and neighborhood with the following structures:

```php
class Property  {

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
protected $address;

/**
 * @var Point $geom
 * @ORM\Column(type="Point", nullable=true)
 */
protected $geom;
}

class Neighborhood  {

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
 protected $gid;

 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
 protected $name;

 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */     
 protected $description;

 /**
 * @var Polygon $geom
 *
 * @ORM\Column(type="Polygon", nullable=true)
 */
 protected $geom;
 }
```

In pgAdminIII, I can write the following query which works fine:

```sql
SELECT address, neighborhood.name
FROM property
JOIN neighborhood
ON ST_Contains(neighborhood.geom, property.geom)
```

How can I write this in DQL?  I understand the basics of joins and adding the annotations for the Doctrine2 mapping, but I am not sure how to do the join since the two fields are not equal.  I need to use the ST_Contains function to create the join.
I am using the djlambert / doctrine2-spatial bundle for the spatial data types and mapping.  I am able to query each table individually and have created maps on each, but am not sure how to select all of the properties in a given neighborhood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured this out and want to post in case someone else has a similar question.  I needed to make the ST_Contains part of a condition and not just the function alone.

using the createQueryBuilder, here is the syntax:

```
 $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('n')              
            ->select("p.address as address, n.ntaname, ST_AsText(p.geom) as function")                
            ->join('Bundle\Entity\Property', 'p', 'WITH', 'ST_Contains(n.geom4326,p.geom)=true');        


    return $qb->getQuery()
                    ->getResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a real answer but just a comment on @George's code.

For me, using `creof/doctrine2-spatial:0.0.1` and `symfony/symfony:2.3.*`, the annotation needed to be lower case for the schema to validate with `php app/console doctrine:schema:validate`, like this :

```
/**
 * @var Point $geom
 * @ORM\Column(type="point", nullable=true)
 */
protected $geom;
```

With a capital case, I kept getting this error message :

```
  [Doctrine\DBALDBALException]                                                                                                 
  Unknown column type "Point" requested. Any Doctrine type that you use has to be registered with \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::addType(). [...]
```

Comment: in my config file, i have point mapped to Point  
    `mapping_types: point:        Point`